# django url issue when trying to load ajax function

Tags: python, ajax, django

In urls.py i have a url like

```
 url(r'^level/(\d+)/ajax/reload/$', views.ajax_change_status, 
 name='ajax_change_status'),

 #Works with this url
 url(r'^level/ajax/reload/$', views.ajax_change_status, 
 name='ajax_change_status'),
```

I want to allow all ids  between the level/*all ids/ajax/reload
When im calling the ajax function it returns status 404, url not found.Now if i replace the (\d+) with any id like 1,23, it works.What could be the issue here?

```
def ajax_change_status(request):
   if request.is_ajax():
     try:
       Notification.objects.filter(receiver=request.user)  
       .update(viewed=True)
       Addnotify.objects.filter(receiver=request.user)
       .update(viewed=True)
       FollowNotify.objects.filter(receiver=request.user)
       .update(viewed=True)
       HubNotify.objects.filter(receiver=request.user)
       .update(viewed=True)

       return JsonResponse({"success": True})
    except Exception as e:
        print('EXCEPTION',e)

        return JsonResponse({"success": False})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax looks good.
Maybe it's because of your last "/" in the REGEX. Did you try to reach the URL with this "/" ?

Comment: Yes,  it doesnt seem its the issue here

Comment: okay now its actually showing a 500 internal server error after the '/' change

Comment: Did you try to change (\d+) by [1-23] ?

Comment: i want all ids , not just 1 to 23 ,could be any integer

Comment: HTTP 500 is better. It means that your URL is reachable.

Comment: Share your "views.ajax_change_status" please

Comment: i have edited the question...The code is working fine with all other urls ,perfectly..IM calling this ajax on various other urls as well

Comment: Its actuallly not printing any exception ..the error im getting in the console is GET http://localhost:8000/student/level/2/ajax/reload/ 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: Im having different urls with the same name.would that be an issue here?

Comment: Your root is /student, you have to start your URL like that :
r'^/student/level/(\d+)/ajax/reload/$

Comment: nope...Actuallly student is the app name and it shoukd point to the correct url